# Cannot use a JSP custom tag library in a facelets page

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsp-tags, custom-tags

I have jsp custom tag library which works fine in web projects using jsp pages. I want to use the custom library in JSF facelets based web project.

Please let know if that's possible.

Registration.xhtml

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"      
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:api="http://www.my.com/taglibs/api">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>    
        <h:body>
            <h2>Registration</h2> <br/>        
            <h:form id="myForm">
                <table>
                <api:function attribute="/value"/>
```

The custom tag (`<api:function>`) appears in the output html without processing. I am using jsf 2.2.8

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? Besides the PrimeFaces namespace declaration, I don't see any relation to it. Tried in a page without PrimeFaces?

Comment: PrimeFaces has no pages... JSF has... JSP (deprecated) and Facelets so this question is ONLY valid if you use it in Facelets (PrimeFaces does not work (good) in JSP) AND if you use a PrimeFaces tag in the page. If you **don't** use a PrimeFaces tag in the page and it still does not work, it is **not** PrimeFaces related. And since you have **no** PrimeFaces tag in your code, the question as it stands is **not** PrimeFaces related. SImple 'deduction'

Comment: ok i updated the question & removed prime face tag in this question. please let know if the taglib works in jsf. [i tested my page by removing the primeface tag, still doesn't work]